# KSOAP2 AndroidHttpTransport.call Error

Tags: android, ksoap2

Trying to get `ksoap2` to work in my app... I have made a web service in .net (VS 2010) and have linked it with `IIS` but when I go to make my `androidhttpTransport.call()` it errors out saying there is an

```
07-30 07:20:40.620: W/System.err(6516): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG     {http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html>@2:44 in     java.io.InputStreamReader@21fc0778)
```

I have done countless research and I still can't find out what is going on... Here is my code:

```
private static final String NAMESPACE   =   "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL         =   "http://blah/this/Service1.asmx";
private static final String METHOD_NAME =  "HelloWorld";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION =  "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";

public void getMessage() {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    //Property which holds input parameter

    List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
    headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic  "+Base64.encode("user:pass".getBytes(), 0)));
    //Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER12);
    Log.i(TAG, "Envelope to String: \n" + String.valueOf(envelope));
    Log.i(TAG, "request to String: \n" + String.valueOf(request));

    envelope.dotNet = true;

    //Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    //Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        //Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
        androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<!--?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?-->");
        blah = androidHttpTransport.requestDump;

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headers);
        //androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        //Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        //Assign it to fahren static variable
        message = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        /*Log.i("HT", blah);
        Log.i("Exception", e.getMessage().toString());*/
    }
}
```

Here is my `response.Dump`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-   strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
        <title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        <!--
            body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-   serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
            fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
            h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
            h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
            h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
            #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans- serif;color:#FFF;
            background-color:#555555;}
            #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
            .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
        -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
                <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
                <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you    supplied.</h3>
            </fieldset></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my logcat from the error:

```
07-30 07:20:40.620: W/System.err(6516): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected:    START_TAG {http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html>@2:44 in   java.io.InputStreamReader@21fc0778) 
07-30 07:20:40.630: W/System.err(6516):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2056)
07-30 07:20:40.630: W/System.err(6516):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:127)
07-30 07:20:40.630: W/System.err(6516):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:96)
07-30 07:20:40.630: W/System.err(6516):     at  org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:189)
07-30 07:20:40.630: W/System.err(6516):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
07-30 07:20:40.630: W/System.err(6516):     at com.example.mysoap.MainActivity.getMessage(MainActivity.java:156)
07-30 07:20:40.630: W/System.err(6516):     at com.example.mysoap.MainActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:90)
07-30 07:20:40.630: W/System.err(6516):     at com.example.mysoap.MainActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-30 07:20:40.630: W/System.err(6516):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-30 07:20:40.630: W/System.err(6516):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-30 07:20:40.630: W/System.err(6516):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-30 07:20:40.630: W/System.err(6516):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-30 07:20:40.630: W/System.err(6516):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-30 07:20:40.630: W/System.err(6516):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

If anybody could please help out I would greatly appreciate it... I am getting desperate..

Comment: "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."

Where do you add credentials to your soap request?

Comment: Well... nowhere now, I had the code in there but it still wasn't working, I'll add what I was trying the edit, gimme a sec